# Русский язык в исходном коде в Dev C++

Tags: windows, c++

Я недавно начал изучать С++, у меня есть компилятор Dev C++. Когда я делаю

```
std::cout<<"Привет!";
```

то получается абракадабра! А если перебираю символы циклом, то русские буквы отображаются правильно. Я думаю проблема в различии кодировок dos и windows. Кто знает какие-нибудь примочки для Dev C++ (типа keycyr для pascal) или операторы/функции/процедуры C++ позволяющие сменить кодировку std::cout.

Comment: Обычно можно воспользоваться `std::wcout` и остальными wide-типами/методами. Однако, насколько помню, в Dev-C++ используется по умолчанию MinGW для компиляции кода, то их там просто [нет](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/wide_characters).

Comment: Зачем вы везде раскопипастили этот костыль? :-(

Comment: Потому что он THE BEST и не "везде" а в двух взаимосвязанных вопросах потому что я хочу помочь таким же как я пользователям Хэшкод если никто не смог помочь мне!

Comment: @Rules, у большинства уже есть свой рабочий способ справиться с этой проблемой и без использования измененного компилятора. Если у **вас не получилось** воспользоваться их опытом, это не значит что это **они не смогли** помочь вам.

Comment: @Rules, в ***UPDATE*** к своему старому ответу привел новый способ ввода-вывода с консолью, основанный на ответе @insolor. 

Сводится к вызову одной функции в самом начале main(). 


Дальше просто работаете с printf()/fgets()/...

--

Посмотрите, может понравится.

Comment: @Rules, тупой вариант нашли вы!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

С `setlocale()` по науке правильно, но если локализация кривовата (как у меня на этой машине), то не работает.

В Windows есть 2 функции, `CharToOem(char, char)` и `OemToChar(char, char)`  для перевода *cp-1251* в *cp-866* (консоль) и обратно.

Пример:

```
#include <windows.h>                                        
#include <stdio.h>                                          
#include <stdlib.h>                                         
#include <string.h>

main ()
{
    char str[1000], buf[1000];
    int itty = isatty(fileno(stdin)),
        otty = isatty(fileno(stdout));

    strcpy(str, "привет");
    if(otty)
        CharToOem(str, str);
    puts(str);

    fgets(str, 1000, stdin);
    if (itty)
        OemToChar(str, str);

    str[strlen(str) - 1] = `\0`;
    if (strstr("привет", str))
        strcpy(buf, "да, часть от 'привет'");
    else
        strcpy(buf, "такого нет в слове 'привет'");
    if(otty)
        CharToOem(buf, buf);
    puts(buf);
}
```

В программе набрано в *cp-1251* (она же *ANSI*).

При вводе с консоли, независимо от `setlocale()` придется переводить кодировку. Также обратите внимание, что параметры командной строки, **набранные в консоли** поступают в программу в кодировке ***cp-1251***!!!

Кодировка в файлах обычно подразумевается в `cp-1251`, это надо учитывать при переадресации (`>`) вывода (`stdout`, `stderr`). Я продемонстрировал в примере, как это можно делать.

***UPDATE***

[@insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor) дал замечательный ответ как правильно программировать работу с
русскими буквами в консоли Windows, используя стандартные функции
`SetConsoleCP(1251)` и `SetConsoleOutputCP(1251)`.

В обсуждении (комментариях) к его ответу можно найти различные детали,
в частности установку русского шрифта.

Похоже его ответ прошел незамеченным для некоторых участников форума.
Поэтому я решил привести функцию, вызов которой в самом начале упрощает
программирование ввода/вывода русских букв в Windows и пример 
ее использования.

1. `cons1251.c`

   ```
   #include <windows.h>                                        

   static int oldin = 0, oldout = 0;

   static void exitfunc()
   {
       SetConsoleCP(oldin); 
       SetConsoleOutputCP(oldout);
   }

   void cons1251 ()
   {
       if (oldin)
           return;

       atexit(exitfunc);

       oldin = GetConsoleCP();
       oldout = GetConsoleOutputCP();
       SetConsoleCP(1251); 
       SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
   ```

   }
2. `rustest.c`

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>                                          
   // русский текст в кодировке cp1251 (она же ANSI)
   // обратите внимание, <windows.h> не нужен

   main()
   {
       printf ("This is russian [аБвГдЕ] before cons1251()\n");
       cons1251();
       printf ("This is russian [аБвГдЕ] after cons1251()\n");


       char str[1000], buf[1000];

       printf ("Привет - введи часть от \"привет\"\n"); fflush(stdout);

       fgets(str,1000,stdin);
       str[strlen(str)-1] = 0;

       printf("Вы ввели: '%s'\n",str); 
       if(strstr("привет",str))
           printf("да, часть от 'привет'\n");
       else
           printf("такого нет в слове 'привет'\n");
       fflush(stdout);

       puts("ждем ввода to exit...");  fflush(stdout);
       fgets(str,1000,stdin);
   }
   ```

Вызов `fflush(stdout)` при работе с консолью (tty) необязателен, однако для вывода в некоторых эмуляторах терминала (например в Emacs eshell) необходим.

Это пример компиляции (Windows 7, Emacs eshell) окно в ***cp1251*** поэтому вывод русского текста и до и после `cons1251()` одинаковый (и правильный).

> ```
> c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc -c cons1251.c 
> c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc rustest.c cons1251.o -o rustest
> c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./rustest
> This is russian [аБвГдЕ] before cons1251()
> This is russian [аБвГдЕ] after cons1251()
> Привет - введи часть от "привет"
> иве
> Вы ввели: 'иве'
> да, часть от 'привет'
> ждем ввода to exit...
>
> c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ 
> c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $
> ```

К сожалению для стандартного cmd-окошка Copy/Paste не работает, так что попробуйте сами.

Для окна с PowerShell в Win 7 этот метод к сожалению не работает (в отличие от «геморройного» `CharToOem`/`OemToChar`).

Надеюсь этот текст окажется кому-то полезным.

***UPDATE 2*** (for @Rules)

Исходный файл `tt.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void cons1251(void);

main()
{
    std::cout << "Привет, введите слово\n";
    cons1251();
    std::cout << "Привет, введите слово\n";
    char str[100];
    std::cin >> str;
    std::cout << "Вы ввели: " << str << std::endl;
}
```

> ```
> c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ g++ tt.cpp cons1251.o -o tt
> c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ ./tt
> Привет, введите слово
> Привет, введите слово
> йцукен
> Вы ввели: йцукен
> c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $
> ```

Пример вывода из эмулятора терминала Emacs eshell. Поэтому первый «Привет...» тоже состоит из нормальных букв. В обычной консоли там «кракозябры», а дальше нормальная кириллица.

**Обращаю особое внимание**. Перед запуском надо **изменить шрифт** в консоли на *Lucida Console*.  Иначе будут кракозябры (но другие). Для замены шрифта кликаете правой кнопкой на надписи *«Командная строка»* окна консоли. В открывшемся меню выбираете *«Свойства»*. В появившемся окне выбираете вкладку *«Шрифт»* и там выбираете *«Lucida Console»*. Потом подтверждаете, что попросит.

Если при подтверждении выбрать пункт *«Изменить ярлык для запуска этого окна»*, то новые окна командной строки будут уже с нужным шрифтом.

Вроде все.

Answer (score 6):

1. Можно сразу редактировать исходник в кодировке cp866, для этого нужен любой редактор, поддерживающий эту кодировку. Например, можно редактировать во встроенном редакторе far manager.
2. В мейне вставляем вызовы двух функций: SetConsoleCP(1251); SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); и при первом запуске устанавливаем шрифт консоли на Lucida Console или Consolas.

Comment: Как устанавливать шрифт ? 

Правой кнопкой мышки в верхней рамке -> Свойства -> Шрифт ?? 

А если программу вызвали двойным кликом по иконке (вместе с консолью) а она должна приветствие выдать ???

--

Набивание текста в cp-866 не спасет от перекодировок (файлы, аргументы, переменные среды).

Comment: Да, шрифт устанавливается так. А для программы делается ярлык с нужным шрифтом консоли.
P.S. по крайней мере это спасает от необходимости постоянных перекодировок при выводе на консоль.

Comment: А ввод с консоли все же руками преобразуете, или SetConsoleCP(1251) вводит в cp-1251 ?

--

Попробовал, переключил шрифт, вызвал chcp 1251, по русски (в смысле cp-1251) и вводит и выводит. 

Только вот вопрос, что делать с **уже написаными** для консоли в cp-866 программами ? Еще больше путаницы будет.

--

@insolor, а Вы не знаете как можно из программы определить в какой кодировке находится консоль ? Лучше бы и ввод и вывод.

Comment: > А ввод с консоли все же руками преобразуете, или SetConsoleCP(1251) вводит в cp-1251 ?
SetConsoleCP(1251) вводит в cp1251, а SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); выводит. С уже написанными программами при наличии исходника можно что-нибудь сделать (если сильно нужно).

>как можно из программы определить в какой кодировке находится консоль? Лучше бы и ввод и вывод.
Очевидно, функциями GetConsoleCP() и GetConsoleOutputCP() (соответственно ввод и вывод) :)

Comment: С удовольствием плюсую. 

Я уже попробовал (вроде работает). Завтра попробую в криво локализованой XP.

Comment: Попробовал еще раз. **Хорошо работает.** 

Поставил шрифт Lucida Console и **о чудо**: текст в cp-866 нормально, потом программа вызывает SetConsoleCP(1251) и SetConsoleOutputCP(1251) и **нормально** пишет-читает в cp-1251 (ничего не проверяю !!!, в перенаправленный stdout тоже ОК). Восстанавливаю (SetConsole...), запомненные ранее (GetConsole...) установки **и опять ВСЕ работает как раньше в cp-866**.

Только сам шрифт некрасивый.

Comment: За баллы спасибо)

> Только сам шрифт некрасивый.

Не знаю, по мне так нормальный. Может сглаживание шрифтов отключено?

Я под XP шрифт Consolas как-то в реестре прописывал (уже не помню как) чтобы можно было в качестве шрифта консоли ставить.

Answer (score 5):

Вам необходимо сменить кодировку локали через функцию `setLocale(): setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian")`. Более подробное описание: [setlocale](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/clocale/setlocale/).

Comment: Еще очень желательно после вывода русского текста восстановить исходную локаль, чтобы не возникло проблем с кодировкой в других частях программы.

Comment: >Еще очень желательно после вывода русского текста восстановить исходную локаль, чтобы не возникло проблем с кодировкой в других частях программы.

 Консольные программы, как правило, небольшие, поэтому проблем быть не должно. А если и большие, то вывод обычно всегда в одном месте. Никто же не будет делать вывод на разных языках! Русского и английского должно хватить.

Comment: В данном случае вы правы, @GLmonster, а также считаю, что для @Rules, если он только начал изучать C++, будет полезным узнать, как поступать с локалью в более общем случае, т.к. после написания консольной утилиты он может вдруг перейти к чему-то более крупному.

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, а почему бы просто не использовать русскую локаль(?):

```
...
#include<clocale>      
...

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");  // русская локаль
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Русский язык в исходном коде в Dev C++

К среде разработки и компилятору это не имеет никакого отношения.

Этот вопрос достаточно распространён. Зачем задавать его лишний раз, если он легко гуглится? Вот некоторые ссылки:

- [Как вывести в консоль русские буквы?](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/faq/?id=3619)
- [Проблема с русским в Visual Studio 2005 (c++)](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=18392)