# Visual C++ 2010 не понимает русский язык

Tags: c++

Компилирую программу, а вместо русских букв закорючки. Как избавиться от этой проблемы?

Comment: Смотрите [здесь]( http://hashcode.ru/questions/117144/русские-символы-при-вводе-и-выводе-на-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В ответах на вопрос [Русский язык в исходном коде в Dev C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/70089) все достаточно подробно (и с примерами) разобрано.

Comment: Точно :) Именно этот вопрос я искал, но перепутал с тем, который привел в комментарии.

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
```