# Не работает смена локали

Tags: кодировка, c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
void Plus(){
int long a,b;
cout << "Введите первое число: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Введите второе число: ";
cin >> b;
cout << "Ваш ответ: " << a + b << endl;
 }
 void Minus(){
int long a, b;
cout << "Введите первое число: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Введите второе число: ";
cin >> b;
cout << "Ваш ответ: " << a - b << endl;
 }
 void Ymnojit(){
int long a, b;
cout << "Введите первое число: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Введите второе число: ";
cin >> b;
cout << "Ваш ответ: " << a * b << endl;
}
 void Podelit(){
int long a, b;
cout << "Введите первое число: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Введите второе число: ";
cin >> b;
cout << "Ваш ответ: " << a / b << endl;
  }
    int main(){
       setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
       int a;
       cout << "Режим:" << endl;
       cin >> a;
       if (a == 1){
         Plus();
} if (a == 2){
    Minus();
} if (a == 3){
    Ymnojit();
} if (a == 4){
    Podelit();
}
system("pause");
return 0;
  }
```

`setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");` -  не помогает.

Comment: Скорее всего шрифт в консоли менять надо.

Comment: Самый надежный способ - убрать setlocale и перейти на линукс. Там это проблемы нет "из коробки".

Comment: @KoVadim: Ну ладно уж вам. Вы ведь на вопрос «как починить забор» не отвечаете «надо менять страну, там все заборы в порядке»?

Comment: @KoVadim ну это огонь вообще.

Comment: @gasfull: `system("chcp 1251");` пробовали?

Comment: @VladD не помогает.

Comment: @gasfull: А что именно происходит, вы предлагаете нам самим догадаться? Попробуйте [вот это](http://www.cyberforum.ru/post848744.html), и будьте добры рассказать, что именно происходит, если говорите «не работает».

Comment: @gasfull, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Тут подобные вопросы обсуждались много-много-... раз.

Попробуйте набрать в гугле:

```
site:hashcode.ru C++ windows русский язык кракозябры
```

и почитать, например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/70089/windows-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2-dev-c).

--

А @KoVadim прав. Не стоит *учиться* программированию на C/C++ в винде (а может, и вообще не стоит уже на нее время тратить).

Comment: Вопрос этот задают часто и также часто дают ответы, которые не работают в том или ином случае. [Вот классика жанра про Виндовую консоль и Юникод](https://web.archive.org/web/20111005003105/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2010/10/07/10072032.aspx). Если ссылка не работает: `https://web.archive.org/web/20111005003105/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2010/10/07/10072032.aspx`

Comment: @avp `> Не стоит учиться программированию на C/C++ в винде` , откуда такое предвзятое отношение?

Comment: @perfect, просто \*nix внутренне прост и красив, в отличии от эклектичной, набитой всяким хламом и уже изначально скованной (посмотрите хотя бы на  разделитель в пути к файлу (`\\`))  совместимостью с прошлым виндой. А уж про разные кодировки русского в консольном вводе и файлах (а также аргументах командной строки (вводимых же с клавиатуры !!!)) я просто молчу.

Comment: @avp , ясно , я вообще на ситуацию с ОС смотрю с точки зрения кроссплатформености , но предпочитаю продукты из коробки , так как они позволяют сосредоточится над тем что необходимо именно сейчас не отвлекаясь на освоение реализации всей системы в совокупности и особенности работы с ней.

Answer (score 1):

```
system("chcp 1251");
```

Мне это помогает, самый простой и удобный вариант если вы учитесь.

`setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");` - можно в данном случае не использовать.

Единственно, в консоли будет лишняя информация такого рода: "Текущая кодовая страница: 1251"

Дальше, когда углубитесь, будут и другие решения, более сложные, универсальные.

Answer (score 0):

используйте функции:

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток ввода
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток вывода
```

подробнее [здесь](http://cppstudio.com/post/435/)