# Не выводятся русские символы в консоль!

Tags: c++, консоль, локализация

Да, тысячный дубликат.

Компилирую из под командной строки, g++ -Wall -std=c++17 -o test.exe main.cpp.
Windows 10 x64 Core i5.

Попытки решения проблемы - установить шрифт Lucida Console, setlocale(), SetConsoleCP(), SetConsoleOutputCP(). Ничто не помогло.

Руководствовался этим: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154).
В первом ответе(собравшем больше всего голосов), прочёл ту часть, которая не относиться к Visual Studio(первые 3 абзаца).

Один из вариантов:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    std::cout << "Привет, Мир!\n";

    return 0;
}

Output: РџСЂРёРІРµС‚, РњРёСЂ! - классно
```

Comment: используйте wcout  вместо  cout

Comment: Попробуйте вариант с  [CharToOem()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/70192/232)

Comment: Попробовал. Не сработало(выводит абракадабру).

Comment: У вас файл программы сохранен в кодировке utf-8. Перекодируйте в cp1251

Comment: @insolor Как? Доступны лишь UTF-8, ANSI, Unicode, Unicode Big Endian, если перекодировать путём "Сохранить как..."

Comment: Вот ANSI попробуйте

Comment: @insolor Совет сохранять в однобайтовой кодировке в 2020 году является крайне бестолковым.

Comment: @user7860670, зато это быстрое решение. Не всем подходит "правильное, но сложное решение" из ответа к вопросу-дубликату.

Comment: @insolor. Да, оно помогло. Но для этого мне пришлось открывать блокнот и нажимать Сохранить как, чтобы поменять кодировку. После этого, если я открой этот файл через Sublime Text 3(основной редакток), то там будет абракадабра. Что в таком случае делать?

Comment: Без понятия, я не работаю в Sublime Text.

Comment: @markussie, в Sublime Text 3 есть кнопка «Reopen with encoding».

Answer (score -3):

Попробуй прописать

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
```

Comment: Внимательнее читайте заданный вопрос. То, что вы предложили, я уже попробовал и мне не помогло.